# Remove rules required from an input date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have an input of type date and i'am doing validation for it.

This input is only required when a checkbox is checked, so i did a function with jquery to add rules required and now i want to remove this rules if my checkbox is not checked.

Here my Html :

```html
<div class="col-md-3 d-inline-block">
   <label class="mdc-text-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateDebutZFU, new { @Value = Model.DateDebutZFU != new DateTime() ? Model.DateDebutZFU.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "", @data_val_date = "La valeur doit être une date", @class = "mdc-text-field__input dataDate" })
      <span class="mdc-floating-label">Date Debut ZFU</span>
      <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
   </label>
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateDebutZFU, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div class="mdc-switch align-top mt-1 mr-5">
   <div class="mdc-switch__track"></div>
   <div class="mdc-switch__thumb-underlay">
      <div class="mdc-switch__thumb">
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ZFU, new { @class = "mdc-switch__native-control", @role = "switch" })
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And Here the function to add rules if i click to the button submit :

```js
function btnclicked() {
    if ($("#btnedit").data('clicked', true)) {

        if (($("#ZFU").is(':checked'))) {
            $("#DateDebutZFU").rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Date Debut ZFU est obligatoire"
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here what i try to do if the checkbox is not checked then i must remove rules of required that was displayed in the input:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ZFU").click(function () {

        var rules = $("#DateDebutZFU").rules();

        if (rules) {

            $("#DateDebutZFU").rules("remove", "required");
        }
    });
});
```

Now my problem that the message required is always displayed despite that the checkbox is not checked so what is the problem in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to evaluate your date input based on checkbox - just do it

```
function btnclicked() {
    if ($("#btnedit").data('clicked', true)) {
    var isChecked = $("#ZFU").is(':checked');
        var $dateDeutZFU = $("#DateDebutZFU");

        if (isChecked) {
            $dateDeutZFU.rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Date Debut ZFU est obligatoire"
                }
            });
        }else{
            $dateDeutZFU.rules("remove", "required");
        }
    }
}
```

Using your example I am checking if `checkbox.is(':checked')` and based on this condition add/remove 'required' rule. ope this will help you.